# Working with scroll down in Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, scrollview, bottom-sheet

I want to scroll the view down when the bottom sheet is fully up (Dragged up to complete screen). It works good when it scrolls up but it does not work when it scrolls down. Rather, the whole bottom sheet comes down. Any way out?

**Main Activity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button fab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog  = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this);
                View parentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sheetlayout,null);
                bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(parentView);
                BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) parentView.getParent());
                bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(
                        (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,100,getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
                        )
                );
                bottomSheetDialog.show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**SheetLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:text="button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:text="button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:text="button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:text="button5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        android:text="button6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button18" />

    <Button
        android:text="button7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:text="button8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button8" />

    <Button
        android:text="button9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        android:text="button10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button10" />

    <Button
        android:text="button11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button11" />

    <Button
        android:text="button12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button12" />

    <Button
        android:text="button13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button13" />

    <Button
        android:text="button14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button14" />

    <Button
        android:text="button15"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button15" />

    <Button
        android:text="button16"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button16" />

    <Button
        android:text="button17"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button17" />

    <Button
        android:text="button18"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button6" />
</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**Edit1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:text="button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />

        <Button
            android:text="button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

        <Button
            android:text="button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button3" />

        <Button
            android:text="button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button4" />

        <Button
            android:text="button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button5" />

        <Button
            android:text="button6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button18" />

        <Button
            android:text="button7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button7" />

        <Button
            android:text="button8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button8" />

        <Button
            android:text="button9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button9" />

        <Button
            android:text="button10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button10" />

        <Button
            android:text="button11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button11" />

        <Button
            android:text="button12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button12" />

        <Button
            android:text="button13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button13" />

        <Button
            android:text="button14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button14" />

        <Button
            android:text="button15"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button15" />

        <Button
            android:text="button16"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button16" />

        <Button
            android:text="button17"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button17" />

        <Button
            android:text="button18"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button6" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**Edit2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <Button
            android:text="@string/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="0.66" />

        <Button
            android:text="button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

        <Button
            android:text="button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button3" />

        <Button
            android:text="button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button4" />

        <Button
            android:text="button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button5" />

        <Button
            android:text="button6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button18" />

        <Button
            android:text="button7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button7" />

        <Button
            android:text="button8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button8" />

        <Button
            android:text="button9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button9" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/button10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button10" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/button11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button11" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/button12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button12" />

        <Button
            android:text="button13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button13" />

        <Button
            android:text="button14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button14" />

        <Button
            android:text="button15"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button15" />

        <Button
            android:text="button16"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button16" />

        <Button
            android:text="button17"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button17" />

        <Button
            android:text="button18"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button6" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ? If yes, please share it.

Answer (score 15):

I had same problem and fixed it using android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView. below is my code for bottom sheet layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
            android:tint="#737373" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Email a Copy"
            android:textColor="#737373"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webpage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"></WebView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

What you just need to do is to **change** the `ScrollView` for a `NestedScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

So far I know **normal Scroll View will not work with Bottom-sheet**, while Scrolling down , `Bottomsheet` will also `get down` , which is `not expected behavior` !

Instead you can **try NestedScrollView** as below :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Any Long Text" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and fixed it using androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView below is my code for bottom sheet layout.

```XML
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--Add your UI here -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```